# gdb local variables in a function

Tags: c++, domain-driven-design, gdb

Is there a way in gdb to check the local variables of a member function and also the class private members. Sometimes, I need to know which variables are local to the function and which ones are class variables.

Best,
Umut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

info local

will print the values of all local variables (see info args if you also want function parameters)

print *this

will show the member variables.